# determine height and width of dynamic html element by jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose i have one js variable and my html data is stored into it like

```
var data = '<div id="tst">here will be my othere html</div>'
```

in this case can i determine that what would be height & width of div tst using jquery?

one guy give me solution like

```
var $test = $(data).appendTo('body');
var size;

window.setTimeout(function(){
 size = {
     height: $test.height(),
     width: $test.width()
 };
 $test.remove();
});
```

but the above code looks bit complicated. if anyone know easy solution then please give me a sample code to do so. thanks

Comment: You need not use the `.setTimeOut()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is enough:

```
//put html from variable at the end of <body>
var $test = $(data).appendTo('body');

//determine height and width and put into one variable for convenience
var size = {
   height: $test.outerHeight(),
   width: $test.outerWidth()
};
```

Please note that it isn't even necessary to use `size`. You could put it into 2 variables `width`and `height`. It is merely a personal preference.

Also note that I prefer to use `.outerHeight()`and `.outerWidth()` because the regular `.width()`/`.height()` don't count the border. It's up to you to decide which ones you actually need ;)

Answer (score -1):

You could do this

on document ready the height will be what you define it here from the ID

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tst").css({'height' : '100px'});
});
```